# Is there anything I can do to make money while in US without work permit?

Tags: usa, immigration

I have a US L-2 visa, which allows me to stay in the US and makes me eligible to work provided I have an Employment Authorization Document (EAD).  Due to USCIS taking excessively long to process EAD extension requests (it's currently taking 5-9 months when it should take 3-5, and requests more than 6 months before the expiry of the current EAD are rejected), I do not currently have a valid EAD (though I do have a job).

My wife has a job (and can work), so for various reasons leaving the US is not an optimal solution at this point.  Is there anything I can do, or am I simply at the mercy of the USCIS?